# mapstruct annotation processor did not generate mappers Implimentation

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster, mapstruct

I have created a spring boot application using the jhipster generator, and then I added to entites author and book, author has many books while a book has one author.

then when I run my app using `Intellij IDEA` I got this stacktrace :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.FastList.iterator(FastList.java:209) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2195) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2105) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2060) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1575) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:447) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]

2016-03-26 16:43:25.866 ERROR 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capvalue.recruite.web.rest.mapper.AuthorMapper com.capvalue.recruite.service.impl.AuthorServiceImpl.authorMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capvalue.recruite.web.rest.mapper.AuthorMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.capvalue.recruite.Application.main(Application.java:74) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.capvalue.recruite.web.rest.mapper.AuthorMapper com.capvalue.recruite.service.impl.AuthorServiceImpl.authorMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capvalue.recruite.web.rest.mapper.AuthorMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capvalue.recruite.web.rest.mapper.AuthorMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

2016-03-26 16:43:25.870  WARN 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

From a similar issue in GitHub (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2399) I understand that mapstruct annotation processor did not generate AuthorMapperImpl.java and BookMapperImpl.java all I can find is AuthorMapper.java and BookMapper.java :

**AuthorMapper.java**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface AuthorMapper {

    AuthorDTO authorToAuthorDTO(Author author);

    @Mapping(target = "books", ignore = true)
    Author authorDTOToAuthor(AuthorDTO authorDTO);
}
```

**BookMapperImpl.java**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface BookMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "author.id", target = "authorId")
    @Mapping(source = "author.name", target = "authorName")
    BookDTO bookToBookDTO(Book book);

    @Mapping(source = "authorId", target = "author")
    Book bookDTOToBook(BookDTO bookDTO);

    default Author authorFromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setId(id);
        return author;
    }
}
```

## JHipster Version

generator-jhipster 2.27.2

## JHipster configuration (.yo-rc.json)

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "com.capvalue.recruite",
    "packageFolder": "com/capvalue/recruite",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "useSass": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "frontendBuilder": "grunt",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "f70fd101e4b03583ba48c96a91e0af7ab6a6c92e",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ]
  }
}
```

## Entity configuration(s)

**Author.json**

```
 {
        "relationships": [
            {
                "relationshipId": 1,
                "relationshipName": "book",
                "otherEntityName": "book",
                "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
                "otherEntityRelationshipName": "author"
            }
        ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldId": 1,
                "fieldName": "name",
                "fieldType": "String",
                "fieldValidateRules": [
                    "required"
                ]
            },
            {
                "fieldId": 2,
                "fieldName": "birthday",
                "fieldType": "LocalDate"
            }
        ],
        "changelogDate": "20160326163433",
        "dto": "mapstruct",
        "service": "serviceImpl",
        "pagination": "pager"
    }
```

**Book.json**

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "author",
            "otherEntityName": "author",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "name"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "title",
            "fieldType": "String",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 2,
            "fieldName": "price",
            "fieldType": "BigDecimal"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160326164101",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "pagination": "pager"
}
```

Comment: As a workaround run 'mvn compile'. Also I recommend you upgrade to JHipster 3.0 and re-generate your project as there is no esy way to upgrade your project

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks it worked but why it didn't work when I run the app using Intellij IDEA, and how can I upgrade JHipster to 3.0 version

Comment: How did you import the project in IntelliJ: as a maven project?

Comment: For jhipster 3, just re-install it 'npm install -g generator-jhipster' and also grunt support has been removed from JHipster so your current setup in 2.27.2 would be a dead end.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes as a maven project

Comment: How do you run the app from IntelliJ?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou from the run button

Comment: You can run it using maven tool in IntelliJ just use spring-boot:run goal, this way you can be sure that anything that must be run before execution is done.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for your help I appreciate it, I upgraded to version 3 as you told me, and then I generated my app using this version, the weird thing is when I try to run my app using `mvn spring:boot run` it doesn't run but instead `mvnw` runs my project

Comment: `mvnw` uses maven wrapper and runs `mvnw spring:boot run`, `mvn` depends on which maven is installed on your system or IDE. So it all depends on how you configured IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

The `UnsupportedOperationException` for HikariCP's FastList iterator was fixed in a more recent version (of HikariCP).  I recommend that you upgrade to HikariCP 2.4.5.